# What are these yellow wildflowers growing in SE Wisconsin?

Tags: identification, wildflowers

I'm pretty sure I self seeded these, but don't remember what they are. I'm guessing the yellow flowers are Black Eyed Susans.

[image: Yellow flowers]

Comment: one identification per question, can you ask a second question with the second photo?

Answer (score 1):

The top flower is a Helianthus, possibly [H. decapetalus](http://minneflora.com/images/identified/medium/thin-leaved-sunflower-helianthus-decapetalus-02.jpg). Helianthus tend to "run" underground and therefore not the greatest plants in a non-meadow garden. H. decapetalus is better behaved then most, though,

The plant is definitely NOT a Rudbeckia.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure that I know the second plant, but that needs to be in a separate question. :)

Comment: I was expecting you. :) Does the latin name of the second plant begin with L?

Comment: @Aleksander - If I'm right, it begins with an M.